# Cnn string for pyodbc with "trusted_connection=yes" instead of userid & password

Tags: python, connection-string

i'm using below code for cnnString, is there any other way without giving userID & password and pass trusted_Connection as true??

```
cnnString = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client11.0};Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXXX'
qry = 'select * from View_Dim_Supp' #or open('myqueryfilepath', 'r').read()
cnn = pyodbc.connect(cnnString)
df = pd.read_sql(qry, cnn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
cnnString = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;trusted_connection=yes'
```